# Auto-update text field depending on selected option

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Rails ver: 4.0.0**

Hi all,

In my form I have a drop-down selection of client names. I would like to have a text box containing the client's address be updated whenever the selection is changed (before clicking the submit button to finalize the update). The reason is I am working with legacy data from another project where there can be several client entries with the same name but different addresses (e.g. large corp with several offices).

Obviously (perhaps?) I can't use any of the client-side script solutions since the new address has to be retrieved from the model - unless there is a way for java/coffee script to do a db lookup that I don't know about (which is highly likely since I only have a superficial acquaintance with them).

Thanks for any hints or pointers.

Comment: You can write a change event handler for the dropdown of client names, fetch the client name currently selected on change and then get the address for the client(via a ajax call to your server) and then update the text fields for address. Are you facing any problems ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this assuming you have @client:

Add a hidden div to your view to hold a data attribute:

```
<div id="client_id" style="display:none;" data-client="<%= @client.id %>"></div>
```

In somefile.js.coffee:

```
App ||= {}

App.client =
address = $("#id_of_your_select_field")
client = $("#client_id).data('client')

toggler.on 'change', ( e ) ->
  App.client.getAddress


getAddress: ->
  $ajax(
    type: 'post'
    url: "/get_address"
    client_id: client
    success: ( data, status, xhr ) ->
    # you could parse JSON here if you want, or keep reading and leave this blank
  )
```

in routes.rb

```
post '/get_address/:client_id', to: 'clients#return_address'
```

in clients_controller.rb

```
def return_address
  @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

and in views/clients/return_address.js do:

```
var clientAddress = $("#the_civ_with_the_address");
clientAddress.html( "<%= j render( :partial => 'clients/address', :locals => { :client => @client } ) %>" );
```

Then make a partial with the client info at app/views/clients/_address.html.erb

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer, @NickM. I will give your solution a try (guess I had better learn Coffee); however, while waiting for responses I came up with something using jQuery that does what I need. It's not pretty in that it has a <script> ... </script> block embedded in the body of a view. Can/should that script block be placed in the application.js file? The jQuery script is used to retrieve the value of the client selection and make an ajax call to retrieve the client's address.